# Setting SET IDENTITY_INSERT for multiple tables in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to set tables `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`. I can for one table at a time. But how can I achieve for more than one as I am doing code-first approach.

I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'Some Table'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'ref.EmploymentType'

**Test.cs**

```
using (var transaction = _referenceDataDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    _referenceDataDbContext.EmploymentType.AddRangeAsync(
                new EmploymentTypeEntity
                {
                    EmploymentTypeID = 1,
                    EmploymentType = "EmploymentType1 ",
                    CategoryTypeID = 27,
                    SiteAddress = null,
                    CreatedBy = "UnitTest",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                    ModifiedBy = "UnitTest",
                    ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,
                    RowVersion = new RowVersion(1),
                    EmploymentTypeGroups = new[]
                    {
                    new EmploymentTypeGroupEntity
                    {
                        EmploymentTypeGroupID = 11, GroupName = "GroupName", IsActive = true
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            );

    _referenceDataDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ref].[EmploymentTypeGroup] ON");
    _referenceDataDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ref].[EmploymentType] ON");

    _referenceDataDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your code is already enabling `IDENTITY_INSERT` for multiple tables.

Comment: As per Sql Server one session can Have only one IDENTITY_INSERT. So my code wont work as it is trying to set for 2 tables

Comment: `But how can I achieve for more than one` You can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SET IDENTITY\_INSERT ON in SQL Server 2008 for multiple tables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615391/how-to-set-identity-insert-on-in-sql-server-2008-for-multiple-tables-at-once)

Comment: EF Core supports Sequences, which allow the client to provide the key values.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences

Answer (score 1):

Remove the lines such as this:

```
 EmploymentTypeGroups = new[]
 {
     new EmploymentTypeGroupEntity
     {
         EmploymentTypeGroupID = 71, GroupName="Some Data", IsActive = true
     }
 }
```

and move `_referenceDataDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ref].[EmploymentType] ON");` to above the `_referenceDataDbContext.EmploymentType.AddRangeAsync(` line.

then turn IDENTITY_INSERT OFF.

Then repeat the whole thing to insert your group records.

This way you only need IDENTITY_INSERT ON for one table at a time.